# Generic XSLT transformation of XML to CSV with dynamic multiple child node

Tags: xml, csv, xslt

i am trying to convert xml to csv using XSLT. i am able to pull data to csv but not all child nodes. From root only 2 level child node are populating in csv. anything below level 3 child node are clubbed into one and populating in csv.
i dont want to mention any elements names in xslt, as xml will be keep changing.

XML used

```
xml  <Tx>
<New>
    <Id>123456</Id>
    <Submitted>true</Submitted>
    <Buyer>
        <AcctOwnr>
            <Id>
                <Gender>Male</Gender>
            </Id>
            <City>GB</City>
        </AcctOwnr>
    </Buyer>
    <Seller>
        <AcctOwnr>
            <Id>
                <Gender>Female</Gender>
            </Id>
            <City>GB</City>
        </AcctOwnr>
    </Seller>
    <Order>
        <TrnsmssnInd>false</TrnsmssnInd>
    </Order>
    <Tx>
        <Date>2019-05-08</Date>
        <cty>DEAL</cty>
        <Qty>
            <Value Ccy="USD">5000</Value>
        </Qty>
        <Price>
            <Price>
                <Value>
                    <Amt Ccy="USD">95.1</Amt>
                </Value>
            </Price>
        </Price>
        <TradVn>XOFF</TradVn>
        <CtryOfBrnch>GB</CtryOfBrnch>
    </Tx>   
    <AddtlAttrbts>
        <TxInd>false</TxInd>
    </AddtlAttrbts>
</New></Tx>
```

XSLT

```
enter code here<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:for-each select="*[1]/*">
        <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
        <xsl:if test="position() != last()">, </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="position() = last()">
            <xsl:text>&#xD;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="iso-8859-1"/>
<xsl:param name="fieldNames" select="'yes'" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
<xsl:template match="/*/child::*">
    <xsl:for-each select="child::*">
        <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
            <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>, </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="position() = last()">
            <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space  (.)"/>
            <xsl:text>&#xD;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>`
```

results what i got from above is

[image]

expected results is

[image]

Comment: Please edit your question to start with a minimal but well-formed XML sample, so far the structure is not well-formed, opens with `<Tx>`, ends with `</New>`.

Comment: Why does the expected result have the value "Male" for both "Buyer.AcctOwnr.Id.Gender" and "Seller.AcctOwnr.Id.Gender"? And in general, what would happen if any third or deeper level structures were repeated e.g. if you had "<New><Id>123455</Id><Id>654321</Id>...</New>`, what kind of output mapping from XML to CSV do you want in that case?

Comment: Buyer and seller gender is typo error.

Comment: expectation is to pull all node and values in csv, even if it repeated it need to be in CSV, new.id = 123456 and new.id= 653224 in 2 diff columns

Comment: We need a much more precise specification of requirements. XML is capable of representing much more complex structures than CSV; some things that can appear in XML are going to be very hard to map to CSV, and we need to know how you want to handle these cases. We can't work out the general rules from one example.

Comment: Generic transformations are difficult to write and they are likely to fail at some point. I would advise you to write a stylesheet custom-tailored to your XML structure.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a generic transformation that returns a data cell for each text node and attribute in the given XML (all in the same row), try something like:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="fruit" select="//*[text()] | //@*" />
    <!-- LABELS -->
    <xsl:for-each select="$fruit">
        <xsl:for-each select="ancestor::*">
            <xsl:value-of select="name()" />
            <xsl:text>.</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:value-of select="name()" />
        <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
            <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    <!-- DATA -->
    <xsl:for-each select="$fruit">
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
        <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
            <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The result of transforming your example XML will be:

```
Tx.New.Id,Tx.New.Submitted,Tx.New.Buyer.AcctOwnr.Id.Gender,Tx.New.Buyer.AcctOwnr.City,Tx.New.Seller.AcctOwnr.Id.Gender,Tx.New.Seller.AcctOwnr.City,Tx.New.Order.TrnsmssnInd,Tx.New.Tx.Date,Tx.New.Tx.cty,Tx.New.Tx.Qty.Value,Tx.New.Tx.Qty.Value.Ccy,Tx.New.Tx.Price.Price.Value.Amt,Tx.New.Tx.Price.Price.Value.Amt.Ccy,Tx.New.Tx.TradVn,Tx.New.Tx.CtryOfBrnch,Tx.New.AddtlAttrbts.TxInd
123456,true,Male,GB,Female,GB,false,2019-05-08,DEAL,5000,USD,95.1,USD,XOFF,GB,false
```

---

Note that this assumes none of the retrieved data contains a comma (as well as a few other assumptions - as I mentioned in the comment to your question, truly generic transformations are difficult to write).

Comment: thq Michael, but it give me only first element Tx.New.Id 123456

Comment: No, the result is what I posted - see: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bnnZX5

Comment: `File stylesheet = new File("C:\\style3.xsl"); 
File xmlSource = new File("C:\\sample.xml");
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document document = builder.parse(xmlSource);
StreamSource stylesource = new StreamSource(stylesheet);
Transformer transformer =TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer(stylesource);
 Source source = new DOMSource(document);
Result outputTarget = new StreamResult(System.out);
transformer.transform(source, outputTarget);`

Comment: i use above to pull data

Comment: I am afraid I cannot help you with that. If you're getting a different result using the same XML input and the same XSLT stylesheet, post a new question

Answer (score 0):

i made some changes to above code and i am able to pull all data

````
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="fruit" select="//*[text()] | //@*" />
    <!-- LABELS -->
    <xsl:for-each select="$fruit">
        <xsl:for-each select="ancestor::*">
            <xsl:value-of select="name()" />
            <xsl:text>.</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:value-of select="name()" />
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:for-each select="child::*">
        <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
            <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    <!-- DATA -->
    <xsl:for-each select="$fruit">
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:for-each select="child::*">
        <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
 <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
</xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>```
````

Comment: This makes no sense. The "fruit" nodes do not have any child elements (at least not in your example XML) so adding the `<xsl:for-each select="child::*">` part does not do anything. All you have achieved is a trailing comma after the last label and the last value.